# C program to find maximum, minimum,sum,average from N numbers inputed by the user using for loop and without using array

Tags: c

I have just started c coding and I am unable to get the minimum value I know that the logic for finding the minimum is wrong but I don't know how to fix it

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
int limit,i;
float a,sum=0.0,max=0.0,min;

printf("Enter the number limit:");
scanf("%d",&limit);
printf("Enter the  numbers:");

   for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
{
   scanf("%f",&a);
    
    if(a>max)
    {
        max=a;
    }
    if(a<min)
    {
        min=a;
    }
    sum=sum+a;
}
printf("\nThe sum of the numbers is:%f",sum);
printf("\nThe average of the numbers is:%f",sum/limit);
printf("\nThe maximum number is:%f",max);
printf("\nThe minimum number is:%f",min);

}
```

Comment: yep, it's wrong. `min` is never initialized...

Comment: A simple way is to include `limits.h` and initialize `min` to `FLT_MAX`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta And also `max` could be initialized to `FLT_MIN` to allow negative numbers.

Comment: @IanAbbott No, FLT_MIN is not what you want. Unlike INT_MIN it's not a negative number...

Comment: @4386427 Oops, I meant initialize `max` to `-FLT_MAX`!

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's float.h, not limits.h

Comment: Enable compiler warnings then pay attention to them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the first value as the initial value of `max` and `min`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int limit,i;
    float a,sum=0.0,max=0.0,min;

    printf("Enter the number limit:");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    printf("Enter the  numbers:");

    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&a);
        if(i==0)
        {
            /* use the first value as the initial value of max and min */
            max=a;
            min=a;
        }
        else
        {
            if(a>max)
            {
                max=a;
            }
            if(a<min)
            {
                min=a;
            }
        }
        sum=sum+a;
    }
    printf("\nThe sum of the numbers is:%f",sum);
    printf("\nThe average of the numbers is:%f",sum/limit);
    printf("\nThe maximum number is:%f",max);
    printf("\nThe minimum number is:%f",min);

}
```

Comment: Made a small edit - hope you are fine with it

Answer (score 1):

You need proper initialization of `min` and `max`.

Do:

```
#include <float.h>

float min = FLT_MAX;    // Set min to maximum positive finite value of float
float max = -FLT_MAX;   // Set min to maximum negative finite value of float
```

then the rest of your code should work.

However, you should check the `scanf` return value, i.e.

```
if (scanf("%f",&a) != 1)
{
   // error handling or simply exit
   exit(1);
}
```

(and likewise for `scanf("%d",&limit);`)

Comment: Should you not use `FLT_MIN`?

Comment: @EdHeal No, FLT_MIN is nothing like INT_MIN. It's the smallest positive number.

Comment: Thanks - learnt summat new today. Is zero positive?